# Doesn't Read-Only make a difference for SQL Server?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005

I’ve been tasked with optimizing a rather nasty stored procedure in a legacy system. It’s a database dedicated to search, and a new copy is being generate every day, with a lot of complex joins being de-normalized. No writes are being performed, only SELECTs, so I figured some easy improvements could be made by making the whole database read-only and changing the recovery model to “Simple”.

Much to my surprise, this didn’t help – at all! The stored procedure still takes the same amount of time of complete. If fact, I’m so surprised that I figured I did it wrong!

My questions:

- Do I need to do anything other than setting “Database read-only” to “true”?
- Am I wrong to expect significant performance improvement by making the database read-only?
- Same for the recovery model: Shouldn’t “Simple” have some noticeable impact?
- Are there other similar database-wide configurations that can improve performance in this scenario?

The stored procedure is huge, with temporary tables, 40+ tables joined in 20+ queries. But I’d like to optimize the database itself before I edit this proc.

Comment: [Some graphs on `readonly` vs `readwrite`](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2007/10/01/performance-impact-setting-a-database-to-read-only.aspx) show you should only expect a modest benefit.  Presumably this query isn't doing any data modifications that would get logged so the recovery model will make no difference. You need to look at the execution plans to identify the actual bottlenecks.

Comment: Maybe you should start with looking at indexes? Creating index can give huge performance impact.

Comment: @Martin, thanks for the pointer, that's an interesting article. I suppose I was wrong in expecting significant performance improvements.

Comment: I would say that your 2 middle assumptions/questions are wrong; the query plan overhead is likely far outweighing any small incremental gains in a read-only, simple recovery model DB.  Fix the thing that's broken.

Comment: @LukLed, all the "obvious" indexes appears to be set correctly, so no easy improvements there either.

Comment: @Jakob Gade: Does this procedure use dynamic SQL? Is it parametrized? Maybe you should divide it in smaller procedure for better caching.

Comment: @LukLed: No dynamic SQL, and it has 29 parameters. I'll try splitting it into multiple procedures.

Comment: [Archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120316025219/sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2007/10/01/performance-impact-setting-a-database-to-read-only.aspx) for the article from @MartinSmith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no writes are performed by your SP, there is no reason to expect noticable performance improvement from changing recovery model and read-write mode.

As others mentioned, you should look into the query plan and optimize your queries.

Another hint: indexes in the database might get fragmented while the database is filled up. Since the data is not going to be modified any more, it might help to rebuild all the indexes with fillfactor 100 - this might help to get rid of fragmentation and to compact data.
Call this for each table in the database: `ALTER INDEX ALL ON table_name REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100)`.
Generally, I won't expect much of performance improvement from this, but it depends on the particular database.

Speaking of query optimization, there are very useful features in SQL Server 2005 and later: [Execution Related](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188068%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and [Index-Related](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187974%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) Dynamic Management Views. In particular, [sys.dm_exec_query_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and [missing indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345524%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) are of interest.
These give you almost the same information as Tuning Advisor, but using you real-life workload, so you don't need to simulate it and feed to the Advisor.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Database Engine Tuning Advisor included in SQL Server? It will analyze your query and suggest new indexes that will improve the performance of the query.  Some of them will be good, some will be bad (for example, I've seen it suggest adding every column in a table to an index, sometimes like 30 of them!), so I don't follow it blindly. Generally I'll add a few indexes and then retest, to find the suggestions that are the most important. I've used it to optimize many queries that I thought I had properly indexed, only to find I could get a lot more performance out of them.

Comment: Yes, I've run the Tuning Advisor, and I will be looking at the indexes very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar setup, large stored procedures with lots of large temp tables.
Our problem was that the joins with and between the temp tables was very slow.
I recommend that you look at your execution plan and try to add relevant indexes to the temp tables too if you have not already.